# PhpStorm Docker remote PHP interpreter stops responding with message "Checking PHP Installation"

Tags: docker, phpstorm

I'm trying to setup development environment using PhpStorm, Docker on Windows 10 machine.

When remote PHP interpreter selected PhpStorm stops responding with message "Checking PHP Installation":
[image]

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
    
    networks:
      symfony:
    
    services:
        #nginx
        nginx-ea:
          image: nginx:stable-alpine
          container_name: nginx-ea
          ports:
            - "8081:80"
    
          volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    
          depends_on:
            - php74-fpm
            - mysql8-ea
          networks:
            - symfony
    
        # php74
        php74-fpm:
          build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
          container_name: php74-fpm
          ports:
            - "9001:9000"
          volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
            - ./php/conf:/usr/local/etc/php/
    
          networks:
            - symfony
    
        php74-cli:
          # define the directory where the build should happened,
          # i.e. where the Dockerfile of the service is located
          # all paths are relative to the location of docker-compose.yml
          build:
            context: ./php-cli
          container_name: php74-cli
          # reserve a tty - otherwise the container shuts down immediately
          # corresponds to the "-i" flag
          tty: true
          # mount the app directory of the host to /var/www in the container
          # corresponds to the "-v" option
          volumes:
            - ./app:/var/www/project
          # connect to the network
          # corresponds to the "--network" option
          networks:
            - symfony
        
        # mysql 8
        mysql8-ea:
          image: mysql:8
          container_name: mysql8-ea
          ports:
            - "4309:3306"
          volumes:
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
          command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
          restart: always # always restart unless stopped manually
          environment:
            MYSQL_USER: root
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
          networks:
            - symfony
    
        #PhpMyAdmin
        phpmyadmin-ea:
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.0.1
          container_name: phpmyadmin-ea
          restart: always
          environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql8-ea
            PMA_USER: root
            PMA_PASSWORD: secret
          ports:
            - "8090:80"
          networks:
            - symfony
```

**Docker Desktop Windows 10 settings**

[image]

Have tried selecting both php74-fpm container and php74-cli container, as soon as settings applied in PhpStorm it stops responding completely.

**Any idea what is wrong in here?**

**UPDATE**

Including PHPStorm logs from system\log\idea.log

```
# appears in logs when Remote PHP Interpreter settings applied

2020-11-27 09:14:00,859 [ 479670]  DEBUG - php.config.phpInfo.PhpInfoUtil - Loaded helper: /opt/.phpstorm_helpers/phpinfo.php 
2020-11-27 09:14:01,106 [ 479917]   INFO - .CloudSilentLoggingHandlerImpl - Creating container... 
2020-11-27 09:14:02,019 [ 480830]   INFO - .CloudSilentLoggingHandlerImpl - Creating container...
```

2 Docker containers are created after Remote PHP Interpreter settings applied however they don't seem to be activating and logs inside the container doesn't seem to say anything

[image]

if try starting "**phpstorm_helpers_PS-191.8026.56**" container manually from docker desktop it seems to start ok

if I manually try to start "**festive_zhukovsky...**" container it doesn't start.
logs inside container prints xml:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5XbkJdHnc7vuN0V7heJdx3lBkmJfs3V/view?usp=sharing

**UPDATE 2**

if i remove local PHP version which comes from xampp package in PHPStorm the windows on the right shows where PHPStorm is hanging and become unresponsive:

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

according to this article https://ollyxar.com/blog/docker-phpstorm-windows
Docker should have Shared Drives configuration
[image]

however I don't seem to have this option in Docker Desktop Settings:
[image]
Can this be a problem?

Comment: Hard to say anything for sure without checking logs first. You may want to add "#com.jetbrains.php" in "Help > Diagnostic Tools > Debug log settings", reproduce the issue and check logs afterwards (Help > Show Log). Probably, it could give us more clues about what is going on.

Comment: Can you share more details? According to that very first image, you are not using a remote interpreter, but a local one

Comment: I have xampp installation and local PHP version used normally comes from xampp package however even if i remove that setup it does the same